# Two subdomain Mapping to one Load Balancer DNS - DNS Violation

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ecs, cname, aws-application-load-balancer

So I have two ECS Cluster in front of which I have an Application Load Balancer, I am using host-based routing to have 2 URL point to 2 different target group associated with the same load balancer.

My two domains are from GoDaddy and I want them directed to the AWS ALB DNS.

The domains have this format:

- container1.company.com
- container2.company.com

According to GoDaddy it is a DNS violation to have two CNAME record pointing to the same DNS, which brings me to my question of how do you use host-based routing if you can't have your hosts point to the same DNS.

I am sure the fact that I am not using Route53 for my domains complicates things but I am thinking there has to be a way to make it work with GoDaddy in such a way that it won't create a violation.

Any suggestions on how to help this?

Comment: Ask Go Daddy for a reference to the spec that says this. It is common to have multiple subdomains map to the same CNAME even with different root domains. I am not aware of any authority that prevents or recommends against this. In the old days, this was a valid issue because of poor software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to CNAME by

```
container1.company.com   CNAME   some.alb.hostname.from.amazon 
container2.company.com   CNAME   some.alb.hostname.from.amazon
```

even if the ALB hostname is the same. 
You may want to share the exact setting you are using

Comment: Isn't this in violation of DNS conventions? Because this is exactly what I did but it's causing one of the URL not to resolve... I pointed each URL to the same amazon ALB DNS

Comment: Please share the exact setting you are using (anonymize the host) , or the error message.

Comment: The CNAME are both pointed to <anonymizedID>.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com, the said ALB has rules on it that said if it's container1.company.com forward to target-group-1, otherwise forward to target-group-2 (host based routing)

Comment: Perhaps I have it backwards and the same url can't have 2 CNAMES but it stills doesn't explain why one url works and the other doesn't...the interesting is the second url partly works it seems, I am able to pull it up on my mac but no-one with a PC has been able to reach out. Also, when I ping the url I get 'Unknwn host' as a response.. Pinging the first URL gives me the ALB's DNS...

Comment: Right, you can't have 2 CNAME for one host. ie you can't do  <container1.company.com> CNAME <target1.host.com>  and <container1.company.com> CNAME <target2.host.com>  as standard/basic DNS, unless you are doing advanced routing like Geo based DNS.

Comment: The DNS lookup and the reverse HTTP/HTTPS proxy using host routing are 2 different parts that need to both work. What do you get when you run `nslookup <container1....>`  and `nslookup <container2...>` ? Once we confirm the DNS lookup is working, you'll than have to make sure the ALB is configured correctly. Are you using httpS or plain httP to test? Maybe you can also try to setup 2 independent ALBs to see if this makes any difference.

Comment: I’ll accept your answer. Turns out we had an error in our subdomain CNAME where it had a typo and was entered incorrectly...so that’s that...